# How to create app to receive sms in android oreo?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have created an app which can receive SMS. I have created this app using a broadcast receiver inside a background service. Now since from android oreo background service does not exists so how to receive SMS in android oreo. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

First you should request permissions：

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

and apply in your code;

Second, use content provider of sms:

```
Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/");

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
String[] projection = new String[] { "body" };//"_id", "address", "person",, "date","type
String where = "";// your condition
Cursor cur = cr.query(SMS_INBOX, projection, where, null, "date desc");
if (null == cur)
    return;
while(cur.moveToNext()) {
    // your code
}
```

Finally, implement your function;

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Required permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Step 2: 
Make a receiver class named `SmsReceiver` and add into Mainifest.xml file.

```
<receiver android:name=".SmsReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
         <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Step 3:
Implement receiver class

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    public static final String SMS_BUNDLE = "pdus";

    String smsReceiveNumber, smsReceivedBody;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
            Bundle intentExtras = intent.getExtras();
            if (intentExtras != null) {
                Object[] sms = (Object[]) intentExtras.get(SMS_BUNDLE);
                String smsMessageStr = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; ++i) {
                    SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);

                    String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                    String address = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();

                    smsMessageStr += "SMS From: " + address + "\n";
                    smsMessageStr += smsBody + "\n";

                    smsReceiveNumber = address;
                    smsReceivedBody = smsBody;
                }


            }
        }

    }
}
```

Step 4: 
Adding runtime permission in the main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (!havePermission()) {
            havePermission();
        }

    }

    public boolean havePermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, i only get broadcast when my app is on, when my app is killed, i don't receive broadcast

Comment: You have to use this into service for background process

Comment: Md Mobinur Rahman, this broadcast should be received without running service, because it is implicit broadcast and it is allowed in Android Oreo

Comment: According to this document: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions Android Oreo can listen to implicit broadcasts without any service.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/process-lifecycle it will help you i think so